# HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE loses value in Oracle when application starts

Tags: hibernate

I've a spring application (3.2.8.RELEASE)

The application uses "hibernate core 4.2.6 FINAL" and "Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final"
When the application insert registers in Oracle tables I see that HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE increases his value, but after restart tomcat, the hibernate_sequence loses his value and it always starts with same value (in my case: 21)

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is configured as validate

I changed the HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE cache from 20 to 2, but after restart the application the cache parameter value is 20 again.

Apparently the hibernate_sequence is created each time when the application starts.

Any ideea about this?

All the id fields have "@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)"

```
@JsonProperty("actualId")
@Id
@Column(name = "DEVICE_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```

Other applications are working fine with same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I saw that there is another app accesing to same database and schema. This app was configured with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create.

Both app were using same schema, then HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE was the same for both apps. The other app was creating it. I configured other schema to the app and now all works fine.